# REST Mapping problems when using Springboot Auth and Jboss EAP 7.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, spring-security-oauth2

I am currently working with  `org.springframework.security` together with JBOSS,
and when we deploy the .war all the requests are denied no matter what(even if we allowed the "/login" service to be used in the config). No matter what we do, the Front end keeps getting "Unauthorized", here is our config:

```
package com.leasys.safo.supplychain.wssupplychain.configuration;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN;
import static org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;

import com.leasys.safo.supplychain.wssupplychain.security.NoRedirectStrategy;
import com.leasys.safo.supplychain.wssupplychain.security.TokenAuthenticationFilter;
import com.leasys.safo.supplychain.wssupplychain.security.TokenAuthenticationProvider;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    private static final RequestMatcher PUBLIC_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
//          new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**")
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login")
    );
    private static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new NegatedRequestMatcher(PUBLIC_URLS);

    @Autowired
    private TokenAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().requestMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(restAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    TokenAuthenticationFilter restAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        TokenAuthenticationFilter filter = new TokenAuthenticationFilter(PROTECTED_URLS);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.setRedirectStrategy(new NoRedirectStrategy());
        return successHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean disableAutoRegistration(TokenAuthenticationFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registration.setEnabled(false);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationEntryPoint forbiddenEntryPoint() {
        return new HttpStatusEntryPoint(FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, there still was the JBPM xml file that had wrong mapping for the REST services, I just needed to delete that file to make everything work again.